# xsd: how to check a number code

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have an xsd file and I need to introduce a new validation. I need to check a city code. The city code is 68, an integer that its always the same.

How can I check for that?

Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
 <xsd:element name="CodCity">
<xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation>City Code has to be 68.</xsd:documentation></xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:int"></xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: post your sample input XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a single `xsd:enumeration` to your `xsd:restriction`: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp

```
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:int">
  <xsd:enumeration value="68"/>
</xsd:restriction>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could have been more specific if you had posted input XML.

Assuming your different sample input XML I am posting answers:

Sample Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testing>68</testing>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="testing" type="citycode" />
  <xs:simpleType name="citycode">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:pattern value="68"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Sample Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testing>Blah blah City code is: 68</testing>
```

XSD [using regex pattern]:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="testing" type="pattern" />
  <xs:simpleType name="pattern">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value=".*68"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

where `.*` is any character (except linefeed), 68 - number 68

one more sample Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testing>Blah blah City code is: '68' and something else</testing>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="testing" type="pattern" />
  <xs:simpleType name="pattern">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value=".*68.*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```